# Power source gives only 6v AC reading

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am replacing a 240v wall mounted convector (500w). After wiring new unit, no power seemed to be getting through. So I tested the voltage from the source at the wall and it only read 6v AC 3 times. What could this be and how to resolve please?

Comment: Sounds like you aren't connected to power and are just reading voltage induced by nearby wires.

Comment: That was with power on. Does that mean it could be a break in eg the live feed?

Comment: Apparently power was not connected despite being on. You need to determine why not and fix it.

Comment: Thanks - could it be defective circuit breaker then? With circuit off there is no reading. When on it's 6v.

Comment: If you get 240 at the breaker, it should be good(for passing power).

Answer (score 1):

There are so many possibilities...

- Broken wire
- Terminal screw not done up properly
- Switch or breaker turned off and not turned on again
- Wired wrong - wrong wires to each terminal of a switch, breaker, plug or whatever
- A wire not actually connected somewhere

Comment: Or failed switch, or... Note that some of these might shake themselves back into contact at any moment; do NOT assume the circuit is safe unless the breaker is off (and you're sure it's right breaker).